# Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571) security.component.ts(3, 8): Error occurs in the template of component SecurityComponent

Tags: angular

My Angular and node version.
Angular CLI: 14.1.0
Node: 14.18.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15

This is my security.component.html

```html
<div class="container" *ngFor="let response of responses">
    {{response.id}} - {{response.tweetData}}
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtClientService } from '../services/jwt-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-security',
  templateUrl: './security.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./security.component.css']
})
export class SecurityComponent implements OnInit {

  authRequest: any = {
    "userName": "pochaiah",
    "password": "hello"
  }
  responses:any;
  constructor(private service: JwtClientService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccessToken(this.authRequest);
  }

  public getAccessToken(authRequest:any) {
    let resp = this.service.generateToken(authRequest);
    resp.subscribe(data=>
      {
        console.log(data);
        this.getAllTweets(data)
      });
  }

  public getAllTweets(token:any){
    let resp = this.service.welcome(token);
    resp.subscribe(data=>{
      this.responses=data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Above are my html and ts file codes.

The codes are working properly when open them in browser but visual studio code is giving "**Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571)
security.component.ts(3, 8): Error occurs in the template of component SecurityComponent.** error while trying to access "response.id" in html file.
I have attatching the log of data
[image: Console.log(data)]

Comment: Please share the result of `console.log(data)` in `getAllTweets`.

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
datePosted: "2022-08-05T06:01:26.253+00:00"
id: "62ecb23692964876452b70c4"
likes: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
reTweet: null
tweetData: "Hi my first tweet"
userName: "raghu"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
datePosted: "2022-08-05T06:01:44.031+00:00"
id: "62ecb24892964876452b70c5"
likes: Array(1)
0: "raghu"
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
reTweet: null
tweetData: "Hi my first tweet"
userName: "prabhas"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: It was a json response